# How to display an image on start of a wpf app?

Tags: wpf, image, onstart

I have a wpf application in mvvm pattern. In main view, I have few links to other views.
But before displaying the contents(that is ... the links) in main view, I need to display an image in main view ....that means...a welcome image will be displayed first to the user...say for 2 seconds...and then display the actual contents.

Can anybody help me plz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to add an image to your project and set it's build action to `SplashScreen` in the property window. This will cause the image to be shown while your application loads.

More details: [How to: Add a Splash Screen to a WPF Application (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886(v=vs.100).aspx).

Advantages:

- It's easy and requires zero coding.
- It's shown very early in the start-up process, i.e., while the WPF DLLs are still being loaded.

Disadvantages:

- You have no control over how long the splash screen is displayed. If you need to do that, you can use the [SplashScreen Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen.aspx) directly.

Comment: Yes now the image is getting displayed...but..its getting displayed just as an image not as a window...i mean ...it looks like first an image comes..then...my window comes in...but i need the image to be displayed inside my window

Answer (score 0):

[SplashScreen Class article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen.aspx)
[How to: Add a Splash Screen to a WPF Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that you want the image to be displayed in a window instead of a "classic" splash screen, let me add a second answer: In your WPF window, do something like this:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="mySplash" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="myContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="mySplash" ... />
        <Grid x:Name="myContent">
            ...
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This will show your `Image` for two seconds, then hide it and show the contents of your `myContent` grid. If you want to have a nice fade from the splash image to the content, you can animate the `Opacity` property (using a `DoubleAnimation`) instead of the `Visibility` property.